# PacketInputStream not moving ahead bytes

Tags: java, byte, arrays, inputstream

I have a PacketInputStream class like this:

```
public class PacketInputStream extends DataInputStream {

    private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    public PacketInputStream(InputStream myis) {
        super(myis);
    }

    public String readString() throws IOException {
        int length = readVarInt();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        readFully(data);
        return new String(data, UTF8);
    }

    public int readVarInt() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (true) {
            int k = read();
            if (k == -1)
                throw new IOException("End of stream");

            i |= (k & 0x7F) << j++ * 7;

            if (j > 5)
                throw new IOException("VarInt too big");

            if ((k & 0x80) != 128)
                break;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public long readVarLong() throws IOException {
        long varInt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            byte b = readByte();
            varInt |= ((long) (b & (i != 9 ? 0x7F : 0x01))) << (i * 7);

            if (i == 9 && (((b & 0x80) == 0x80) || ((b & 0x7E) != 0)))
                throw new IOException("VarInt too big");
            if ((b & 0x80) != 0x80)
                break;
        }

        return varInt;
    }

    public byte[] readBytes() throws IOException {
        return readBytes(readShort());
    }

    public byte[] readBytes(int length) throws IOException {
        if (length < 0)
            throw new IOException("Invalid array length");
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        readFully(data);
        return data;
    }

}
```

And I have this code running:

```
System.out.println("Logic data version (always 0) : " + is.readVarInt());
        System.out.println("User ID: " + is.readVarLong());
        System.out.println("Home ID: " + is.readVarLong());
```

`is` is defined

Now the problem I am having is that it is always showing me 0 as the returned number.

Here is the first bit of the inputstream:
`00000000000000030035C708000000030035C708010000004` Now as you can see it shouldn't be giving 0 each time for the first 3 so where is the error and how can I fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you think that an int is represented on your file? You are reading bytes, but the composition and termination condition look very funny to me. - Is the User ID supposed to be 3?

Comment: Looks like `readVarInt()` and `readVarLong()` use variable-length integer encoding, so the result you are getting is not unexpected.

Comment: Did you write this class PacketInputStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your way of input is not as per the code or the code is not as per the input. Here is how I could execute the code:

### main()

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(new byte[] { 0, 3,
            4, 5, (byte)128, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0XC, 7, 0, (byte)8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0XC, 7, 0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4 });
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
    PacketInputStream is = new PacketInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
    System.out
            .println("Logic data version (always 0) : " + is.readVarInt());
    System.out.println("User ID: " + is.readVarLong());
    System.out.println("Home ID: " + is.readVarLong());
}
```

More items to look into:

1. Why `i |= (k & 0x7F) << j++ * 7;`? why not `i |= (k & 0xFF) << j++ * 7;`
2. Why `int k = read();' and not`byte k = readByte();`? Is varinteger size > varlong size where you read by byte?
3. Why `if ((k & 0x80) != 128)` and not `if ((k & 0x80) == 128)`? I believe `if ((k & 0x80) != 128)` is the condition you look forward to terminate reading integer.
4. Should `if ((b & 0x80) != 0x80)` be `if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80)`?

Below is the modified class which I tried to read varint followed by two varlong for my input:

```
    class PacketInputStream extends DataInputStream {

        private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        public PacketInputStream(InputStream myis) {
            super(myis);
        }

        public String readString() throws IOException {
            int length = readVarInt();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            readFully(data);
            return new String(data, UTF8);
        }

        public int readVarInt() throws IOException {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (true) {
                byte k = readByte();
                if (k == -1)
                    throw new IOException("End of stream");

                i |= (k & 0xFF) << j++ * 7;

                if (j > 5)
                    throw new IOException("VarInt too big");

                if ((k & 0x80) == 128)
                    break;
            }

            return i;
        }

        public long readVarLong() throws IOException {
            long varInt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                byte b = readByte();
                varInt |= ((long) (b & (i != 9 ? 0x7F : 0x01))) << (i * 7);

                if (i == 9 && (((b & 0x80) == 0x80) || ((b & 0x7E) != 0)))
                    throw new IOException("VarInt too big");
                if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80)
                    break;
            }

            return varInt;
        }

        public byte[] readBytes() throws IOException {
            return readBytes(readShort());
        }

        public byte[] readBytes(int length) throws IOException {
            if (length < 0)
                throw new IOException("Invalid array length");
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            readFully(data);
            return data;
        }

    }
```